# How do I make a shortcut using WiX that points to an Icon in an already installed EXE/dll file?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

### How do I make a shortcut using WiX that points to an Icon in an already installed EXE/dll file that is not part of my own installer?

For example: I want to use %SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll as my Icon source and point out icon  index number 13.

To me it seems like you must have an Icon entry in WiX for it to reference an included icon. But I do not want to include it, I want to reference something not included. What is the syntax in WiX for this?

I am using WiX 3.5 and must support operating system from Windows XP up to Windows 8.1 and their server counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. i think you just use path to file of [Icon Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/icon.html). From [this tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html), you can read something like this:

> To set an optional icon for the shortcut you need to first include the
>   icon in your installer using the *Icon* element, then reference it
>   using the Icon attribute on the Shortcut element.

So first you need use *Icon Element* to include icon to installer, then use it on *Shortcut* (**attribute *Icon***).

@Update

**Example:**

First define *Icon element*:

```
<Icon Id="MyIcon" SourceFile="icon.ico"/>
```

Then, in your **Component** to which this shortcut should reference, add:

```
<Component Id="CompId" Guid="YOUR-GUID">
        <File Id="FileId" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" Source="..\Converter\Web.config" />
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
                  Name="Buzka"
                  Description="Buzka test"
                  Icon="MyIcon"
                  Target="[#FileId]"
                  WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"/>
</Component>
```

Comment: But this includes a ICON file (icon.ico) that is not present on the WiX build computer. I want to reference a file only available on the install target.
(Any addition of Icons to the MSI icon table seams to install the icon file as a separate file in a hidden location. I do not want this either)

Comment: Oh, you wanna get icon from path at machine you're installing? I dont think its possible, because Icon is INSIDE .msi file, maybe you could write CA and modify table _Icon_ -> _Data_... It's binary data so... manually its possible with **Orca.exe** (i tested it now) i just replaced Binary Data and it worked, but dont really know how to do it from CA... but dunno if it will work, cause MSI will be opened then :/

Comment: Basically I want to edit the location of a resource just like you can manually edit a Windows shortcut and take an Icon from a system-dll using Right Click->Change icon->Write wanted DLL/exe->Select any icon inside resource. But doing this by using WiX. Would I really have to do a Win32 call to manually create a ShortCut (or rather edit it, since otherwise I need a CA for cleanup too).

Comment: I've got idea, why not run CA after installation, that will change icon? it should be preety easy, i mean... if you would know where this file is (or you can get path from some dialog thru PathEdit or something similiar - just for files) you could use `this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(pathToFile.ico);` it should solve your question or i didnt understand question another time? :P

Comment: Seems strange that it might not be possible to achieve this using pure Windows Installer or WiX code.
I do not use C# from the installer but I imagine there is alitte more to editing the shortcut than this? Or is there a special CA just to invoke just as the shortcut is created? Otherwise there would a lot of code for finding and later editing the shortcut (Shell/Win32 calls)?